# Best approach for Java client to post on facebook

Tags: java, javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need my Java (Swing) client application to be able to post a message (with a link and a picture) on the user's facebook profile (which requires the user to login Facebook and authorize the publication).

I can see 3 options:

1. Make use of RestFB API directly from Java. But I'm not clear on how my app would interact with the internet browser (e.g. for the user to login to facebook).
2. Have my java app open a browser on the apps' website (my PHP server) and make use of Facebook's PHP SDK (but this case has the disadvantage of creating extra load on my server)
3. Same approach than (2) but use Facebook's Javascript SDK (in this case I'm not sure how to publish a picture that is stored locally)

From what I understood so far, option (3) seems the easiest (no server load, no app token needed, etc.).

But as I'm new to all this, I'm looking for some guidance on what the simplest approach would be.

Many thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should recommend using the RestFB API, it was designed for what you need.

To login, you'll need to create a Facebook Application and use it to obtain OAuth tokens for your users, documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.1

Here is the full documentation: http://restfb.com/

Since you are using Swing, you will have to open a browser, try this snippet:

```
public static void openWebpage(URI uri) {
    Desktop desktop = Desktop.isDesktopSupported() ? Desktop.getDesktop() : null;
    if (desktop != null && desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE)) {
        try {
            desktop.browse(uri);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static void openWebpage(URL url) {
    try {
        openWebpage(url.toURI());
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Or you can use this other approach:
http://java.dzone.com/articles/web-browser-your-java-swing

---- Edited ----

Since you will have to create another application to get the token, that is not going to be a problem.
Your swing application call a Web Application for login. Inside it, you will have some code like this:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    console.log(response.authResponse.accessToken);
  }
});
```

That is the token, you can save it in a temporary file, or send it to your swing application in many ways.

Comment: Thanks but how will RestFB open a web-browser if the user needs to login to Facebook and give permission to my app? This is really unclear to me. Thx

Comment: Thanks a lot but I still don't get how RestFB will be able to communicate with the browser to get an authorization token to publish (it also needs to get the user's facebook id from the browser)?

Comment: Well, i understood your problem and edited again. Maybe it can help

Comment: Thx. I ended up using DJNative's integrated browser as it enables to very easily communicate with Java